# Plotly barplot not rendering fine in streamlit app

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, streamlit

When rendering a plotly barplot with `fig.show()`, I get the plot exactly the way I developed it. But when I render it using streamlit's `st.plotly_chart()`, it gets with another appearance (without the bar labels).

This is how it should be (the plot I get when using `fig.show()`):

[image]

How it renders with `st.plotly_chart()` (dark theme):

[image]

And in light theme:

[image]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='Current_Base')
fig = px.histogram(df,
                   x='number',
                   text_auto=True
                   )
fig.show()
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

My relevant settings:

```
- os: macOS Monterey 12.1
- libs:
   streamlit 1.3.1
   plotly 5.5.0
```

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Streamlit is converting the graph based on the theme, so if you are in a dark theme, it will convert the plotly chart to match

Comment: I already thought it could be happening. But even in light theme, the bar labels are not showing.